# How to print text in Python that gets rendered as markdown?

Tags: python, python-3.x, markdown, pandoc

I use [stitch](https://github.com/pystitch/stitch) to convert an md file to pdf. However, the text I print in Python doesn't get rendered as markdown. Why?

````
---
title: Doc title
author: Me

---

# Title outside of Python

```{python, echo=False, results='asis'}
for i in range(0,5):
  print('  # Title inside Python')
  print(i, '  \newpage')
```
````

Comment: knitr does the same thing—the output of your program is treated as just that: output, nothing special.

Comment: There is no way to programmatically add markdown text, for example in a loop?

Comment: @tobip, not within Markdown itself. But you can write programs that _output_ Markdown.